# 2021 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2021 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://apple.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: Just logged in for the first time after my recent summer holiday, saw the election notification, and then saw that I was too late! As a general point, is it sensible to have elections during holiday periods when many site users are likely to be away for a prolonged time (look at the poor level of visits/participation in the election)? I'd argue that election periods should be at least 1 month long, and should avoid July, August and December, January, to avoid the main summer holiday periods in both hemispheres, and to increase the chance that slightly less frequent site users can participate?