# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #5](https://apple.stackexchange.com/election/5) on Ask Different has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Nimesh Neema]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/election/5) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5210652701360128).

Comment: Just logged in for the first time after my recent summer holiday, saw the election notification, and then saw that I was too late! As a general point, is it sensible to have elections during holiday periods when many site users are likely to be away for a prolonged time (look at the poor level of visits/participation in the election)? I'd argue that election periods should be at least 1 month long, and should avoid July, August and December, January, to avoid the main summer holiday periods in both hemispheres, and to increase the chance that slightly less frequent site users can participate?

Comment: (Note that I also added the above comment to the https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4030/2021-community-moderator-election post, but am also adding it here, as I suspect it may not be noticed in the election notification post now?)

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to everyone who participated and congrats to Nimesh! It is very clear that both you and Frank have a lot of support here to help moderate.